# How to access Azure ARM Get VNet Reource Group with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I need find resource group of VNet(Virtual Network) with powershell command.

Comment: what do you know? only the name?

Comment: I have Vnet Name along with Subscription ID and other information

Comment: what other information? do you have resource group name if you have other information

Comment: I have the resource group name where machine will be deployed. But VNET have different parent(Resource Group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in the same subscription, you can just do:

```
Get-AzVirtualNetwork  | ? name -eq 'name_goes_here'
```

if you are in a different subscription you need to change subscriptions first:

```
Select-AzSubscription "sub_name_goes_here"
```